# Droid X Turns Itself on Automatically

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-x

I turn off my Droid X (now running Gingerbread) to conserve the battery.  However, every morning when I wake up, it is turned on.  Has anyone else been having this problem?

I don't know how long it waits to turn on, or what time it is that it turns on, but it's quite a pain (especially because it drains the battery).

Any suggestions?  This has only started happening when Verizon upgraded me to Gingerbread.

Comment: are you sure you turned it off correctly? Unless you probably had a short circuit at a very specific place and in such regularity, there is nothing else I can think of that could cause a properly turned off android On.

Comment: Skynet.  Don't you see? We can't even turn our phones off. AHHHH!!!!!

Comment: Mine turns itself back on immediately... or 5 minutes later.. sometimes an hour later. But it always turns itself back on.
I figure it's because I'm on a government watchlist and they're listening... so I take the battery out every night.

Comment: If you can find the system uptime, you might be able to tell a pattern. To get that, I go into the phone app and dial *#*#4636#*#*, then select Battery Info.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same problem. I have confirmed that my phone is powering off (I get the "powering off" message and then the screen goes blank). But some time in the night, my phone turns on by itself.

At first I thought that I was accidentally just setting it into the new (with Gingerbread) sleep mode. But I'm careful and I'm definitely pressing "power off".

Lots of people are reporting this same problem. Other forums have suggested changing the timing of the backup assistant. I've tried that, but to no avail.

It seems clear that this is a new issue with Gingerbread.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are actually selecting "Power Off", not just pressing the power button. If the device is actually powered off, it will not turn back on. It would be like shutting off your computer fully, without pushing the power button again, it will not turn back on.

I want to add, that some devices, like the Samsung Galaxy S for example, even when in the "off state", are not actually off when they have some other power source plugged in. They show some type of status on screen about the battery charge state. If the device does this, then it is completely possible for it to turn back on at some point. But if you do not have any external power source plugged in, and you even took the battery out to "confirm" that it is off, then it should not turn back on and that is some crazy bug, if you ask me...

Comment: It is actually powering off, and it does turn back on.

Comment: I would suggest trying to turn off the phone, pop out the battery, then put the battery back in. if it turns on again, call John Connor, because you have a skynet enabled device. Or contact the manufacturer, it should not power back up on its own.

Answer (score 1):

My Droid 3 turns back on when I put it in my new case.  Come to find out is that the Droid series uses magnetic detection for when you put it in their dock.  If you have a case with a magnetic closure that can tun your phone back on.  It thinks that you are putting in a dock.

Comment: It's not in a case, nor is it near magnets.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Services have the ability to wake the phone up in order to run and it very well could be Motorola or a 3rd party app. I would recommend installing a log viewer app like [logcat](http://market.android.com/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.logviewer&feature=search_result) (I am not the dev) but I use it...

Then in the morning when your phone has started back up, look through the log files. You should be able to determine the Service that gets started and wakes up your phone. You are going to want to expand the log entries in order to see the timestamp.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not if the phone is fully powered of as the OP says.

Answer (score -2):

Most devices turn on when they have reached a fully charged battery state. If you're charging it overnight and you turn it off right before you go to bed, it probably reaches a full charge in the middle of the night and turns on.

Comment: It's not plugged in at the time.

Comment: and it doesn't turn on when its full anyway.