# Toshiba AC100 running Android 2.2 wakes up by itself

Tags: standby, toshiba-ac100

My Toshiba AC100 running Android 2.2 wakes up by itself after an hour or so.

Is there a way to find out which app is waking it up, or to disable waking up system-wide?

Comment: Sounds like the same issue described here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/droid-x-turns-itself-on-automatically (Sadly, no solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its a known issue accordingly to this [Modaco](http://www.modaco.com/topic/318484-experiences-with-the-toshiba-ac-100/) thread specifically posting #8

> Still have a standby bug, (it has a "self wake up")

Perhaps Toshiba has released a fix by now, or, try another custom ROM, perhaps on xda maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about that device, but my Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant would wake itself up when it was on the charger, after it was fully charged. This, to me, was the dumbest thing they did.

Comment: no, it sleeps for a while and then it wakes up without a reason